Accumulating attendance between numerous sheets (Google Sheets)
I need to accumulate attendance counts from numerous sheets (1 sheet per day).
Right now it would make me manually enter every formula as ='6/14/24'!C23 and change each function to match the title for every specific day.
I want this function to utilize the text in column b which matches the naming of the sheet tabs to import it into the function. I was thinking something like ='B3'!C23
This way I could replicate the formula from cumulative attendance into every teacher's attendance document without having to manually enter the names of each sheet for each day, for each teacher.



You may try:
=indirect(B3&"!C23")

OR
=indirect(to_text(B3)&"!C23")

